# cryptsetup create quits after a first password letter

Tags: cryptsetup, amazon-linux

I've got a simple script that's been used for years and years on one particular server to mount an encrypted home partition. It's got this line to create /dev/mapper/cr_sdb1:

```
cryptsetup create cr_sdb1 /dev/xvdb1
```

It's been a few months since the server was last rebooted and back then this worked. But now it doesn't. The `cryptsetup create` asks for a password but exits immediately as soon as I press the first letter of the password (e.g. 'P' for 'Passw0rd' obviously).

```
~ # cryptsetup create cr_sdb1 /dev/xvdb1 
Enter passphrase: P
~ #
```

No Enter, no error, no nothing. It just won't let me enter the whole password.

This is a very old Amazon Linux 1. The `cryptsetup` package doesn't seem to have been updated anytime lately, the install date is 2016.

Why would that be? And how can I fix that?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lsblk -f /dev/xvdb1`?

Comment: Try running it with gdb and execute a backtrace. See if there's a funny silent error.

Comment: My guess is that cryptsetup is giving you segfault.  You would need to debug it for more information